# C++14 support in GCC is experimental

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14, g++4.9

Quoting from the [GCC page on C++14 support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html)

> Important: Because the final ISO C++14 standard was only recently published, GCC's support is **experimental**. No attempt will be made to maintain backward compatibility with implementations of C++14 features that do not reflect the final standard.

I could not find the official GCC definition of `experimental`. Does it only apply to backward compatibility wrt non-standard features, as the last sentence mentions? Or does it also indicate stability, or lack thereof? An earlier sentence on the same page says

> C++14 features are available as part of the "mainline" GCC compiler in the trunk of GCC's Subversion repository and in GCC 4.8 and later.

To me, this suggests stability. Is this the case? In particular, my question is about GCC 4.9, since that is the earliest version with full C++14 support, according to the aforementioned page.

Comment: Why do you care? The GCC folks are trying to do their reasonable best, without warranties!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't see how GCC doing their best equates to not needing to care about stability.

Comment: 4.9 does NOT support all C++14 language features. 5.0 will, IIRC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "official GCC definition", only the official *English* definition.

The passage means that, where GCC previously implemented experimental prototypes of then-upcoming C++14 features *before* C++14 was published, future versions will not bother to try to maintain backward compatibility with those experiments.

Backward compatibility between two versions is only maintained with respect to features that were in an International Standard at the time that they were included in those versions.

This is because, prior to standard publication, the specification of new C++ features can change rather dramatically. It would be madness to guarantee that early experiments in support for them would be forwards compatible with the final, true feature as eventually published in a standard.

In short: **use experimental features at your own risk and do not expect them to work the same way in the next version of GCC**.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, not promising backward compatibility with non-standard features in completely expected - this is clear from the quote and would be crazy to expect otherwise. My question is if this is the only caveat intended.

Comment: And I just noticed that their [C++11 support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) says almost the same thing - `Important: GCC's support for C++11 is still experimental. Some features were implemented based on early proposals, and no attempt will be made to maintain backward compatibility when they are updated to match the final C++11 standard.`

Comment: @Pradhan: Well, I didn't just make it up! :)

Comment: Er... sorry if I am being dense, but I didn't get that.

Comment: @Pradhan: What didn't you get?

Comment: "Well, I didn't just make it up". Also, does "experimental" imply instability and untestedness of the existing implementation?

Comment: @Prahan: No, not necessarily. It implies a lack of guarantee of stability and testedness. That's not the same as implying instability and untestedness!

Comment: There are tens of developers making significant contributions to the gcc standard C++ library: what are the odds that tens of developers would let a bug through?  ;)

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I understand that :) But I am guessing there is a time when a version will be marked "Don't bet your life on it, but I am pretty sure this does what it's supposed to."

Comment: C++11 support in GCC 5 should be non-experimental, and _maybe_ C++14 support too.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks!