# Difference of uninitialized values for g++ and g++14

Tags: c++

If I compile and run a simple program in c++ like this:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

and I compile in Linux saying g++ myProgram.cc (or g++ -std=c++14), I obviously get the ./a.out executable which works fine and the automatically initialized value 0 prints.

But if I compile my code with g++14 myProgram.cc, I get an error saying that x is uninitialized.

Is g++14 some sort of different version? I'm confused on why this is happening, thanks!

Comment: Neither. Just a compiler happening, for some reason, to issue a diagnostic only in C++14. Whether it's C++11, or C++14, or any C++ version, the above program is undefined behavior, and is broken.

Comment: Oh it is broken? I thought the C++ standard for uninitialized values were 0 for numbers and empty for chars and strings.. And default constructors for structs and classes, is this not true??

Should I avoid doing this no matter what? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: We cannot know what `g++14` is. That depends on how your system is setup, it has nothing to do with C++. You can try to run `which g++14` to figure out what file is executed when you use that and have a look into it. I suspect that it is simply calling `g++ -std=c++14` meaning that it compiles against the C++14 version of C++ by default.

Comment: That is true only for statically-scoped values. Not automatic storage.

Comment: @ming That is wrong. Local automatic variables have indeterminate values after default-initialization (which is what you are using here). You always need to initialize with a value explicitly. This does not apply to variables with static storage duration, though (e.g. global variables). Your program has undefined behavior whether there is a warning/error message or not. And yes you should always initialize your variables, no matter how they are scoped.

Comment: For class types such as `std::string`, default initialization (such as `std::string s;`) usually initializes correctly (e.g. an empty string). But e.g. plain-old-data structures such as `struct S { int a; };` do leave their values uninitialized when default-initialized. To be on the save side you may want to simply always use the `{}` initializer: `std::string s{}` or `int x{};` or `S s{};`. It behaves the way you described.

Comment: @uneven_mark ooh ok thank you. And what do you mean by it's okay with global variables, you mean ones outside of functions like main? or like extern int x; ?

And what does the compiler provided default constructor do for classes' fields?

Comment: @ming Yes, variables declared outside any function or class are global and are zero-initialized if no initializer is given. The compiler-generated default-constructor default-initializes all members, meaning that if the member is fundamental type it will have indeterminate value and otherwise if it is class-type it depends on what that classes default constructor does.

Answer (score 1):

From the [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) section of the C++ reference (valid for all versions). You can infer that local non static primitive type variables are not automatically initialized to a well known value/state when declared, you have to do it explicitly. Note that, albeit not being initialized, they **do** contain a value, but it's not deterministic, it could be anything, hence the (paramount) importance of *explicit initialization* by you. Thus, ensuring a well known and defined state for the variable. Your code, actually exhibits what is known as *undefined behavior*, because it uses a variable with an unkown and undefined value/state.

This is valid for all versions of C++. Therefore:

- Your compiler might have a bug, unlikely for something as simple as initialization rules.
- It could be an *implementation specific* detail of your compiler.
- That command might be calling *something else*.

As a good practice, that will save you from many bugs in the future, **always initialize your variables as soon as possible before using them**.

Answer (score 1):

> the automatically initialized value 0 prints.

***No,*** a thousand times, no :-)

Automatic variables are *not* initialised implicitly<sup>(a)</sup>. A particular *implementation* may initialise them to specific values but that is not mandated or guaranteed by the standard.

The *solution* to your issue is to *explicitly* initialise it (or otherwise assign to it before you try to use it).

In other words, use:

```
int x = 0;
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Classes or structures with constructors are obviously initialised but that is not the case here, as you're using a simple `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

g++ -std=c++14 <> g++14

gcc is wonky in places:

[From another post about GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963942/c14-support-in-gcc-is-experimental)

There is no "official GCC definition", only the official English definition.

The passage means that, where GCC previously implemented experimental prototypes of then-upcoming C++14 features before C++14 was published, future versions will not bother to try to maintain backward compatibility with those experiments.

Backward compatibility between two versions is only maintained with respect to features that were in an International Standard at the time that they were included in those versions.

This is because, prior to standard publication, the specification of new C++ features can change rather dramatically. It would be madness to guarantee that early experiments in support for them would be forwards compatible with the final, true feature as eventually published in a standard.

In short: use experimental features at your own risk and do not expect them to work the same way in the next version of GCC.